# How to make a MKMap fit inside the specified View-Region?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mkmapview

i've got a little Problem on setting up a MKMapView.
I really just want that the complete map fits into the MkMapView-Region specified inside
the Storyboard.
But it seems that it is not possible to zoom or scale the map, with the result that the whole world is visible.
Here is what it looks like:

[image]

So if i want to show the connected annotations at the same time, it wont work if they are to far away from each other. Cause it is not possible to make the whole map fit.
Maybe i am missing a step on setting the MapView up but i dont get it.
Any Ideas what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method of MKMapView

```
- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to set center point and zoom level.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the right answer. With setregion i can set the Mapviews region itself. But it seems that there are some bounds on how big the MkmMapView has to be so that the complete map fits inside the view. But i want to make it fit to any size.

Comment: The world map square, you can't see the entire map at once unless you have a square view. Mert's answer is correct. Perhaps your MKMapView is actually larger than you have show, but part of it is hidden by other views.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

If there is only 1 annotation, then lets have a good zoom say 10x. Else zoom till we just see all the annotations ( + some extra padding :)

```
if ([currentMapView.annotations count] == 1) {
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.02;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.02;
} else {
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
}
```